# Inbound REST integration web service

Tags: rest-api, rest

I want to get leads which is getting cerated on a another server, when every time it get created. Eg : In broadbean when the new person register i wan to save the information of the register person to my salesforce object also. So how can I know that the new person have register broadbean. Can anyone give me idea how can I achieve this. I wan to use REST Api.